# PHP cURL downloading 0 bytes from https page accessible only with username and password

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a zip file from Lending Club's website (www.lendingclub.com).

So far I established that I have to be logged in in order to download the file. The download url is something like:

https://resources.lendingclub.com/secure/LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip?signature=Cw8BbuYYmWJW7EOZzeSBb3WUi1k%3D&issued=1459640781435

The signature and issued fields change each time I log in to the site. If I copy and paste the url to a different browser window I am able to download the file.

I believe the site checks for a valid signature and issued before it allows me to download the file.

I am able to login to the site and navigate to the page where the file is. I am using cURL to do so. I am able to capture the specific url with the signature and issued fields. However, when I do the cURL to download it, I receive a response with a http code 401.

It seems that the site does not recognize that I am logged in and responds with the 401 code.

Below is the code I am using to login and to download the file:

```
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
$url = 'https://www.lendingclub.com/account/login.action';

//first cURL request to obtain cookie
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//second cURL request to submit my login credentials and login to the site
$fields = array( 
    'login_email' => 'email@example.com', 
    'login_password' => 'mypassword', 
);
$fields_string = ''; 
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&'); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//third cURL request to get url where the file I want to download is.
$url = 'https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

//regular expression to capture the url (with signature and issued fields)
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/resources\.lendingclub\.com\/secure[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $output, $parts);
$url3a = $parts[0][0];
OutputMsg($url3a); //output the url to confirm I captured the whole url including the query string

//fourth cURL to download the zip file
set_time_limit(0); //prevent timeout
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'testfile.zip', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5040);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url3a); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
var_dump($info);
var_dump($output);
return;
```

My response is something like:

```
array(23) { ["url"]=> string(135) "https://resources.lendingclub.com/secure/LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip?signature=LoEEC1JOFCjfwhv3y6atOMnD2rA%3D&issued=1459641477069" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(401) ["header_size"]=> int(201) ["request_size"]=> int(192) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.229254) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.026935) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.065868) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.187812) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(0) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.22921) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "216.115.73.151" ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" } bool(true)
```

Any suggestions on what I could do different to download the file?

Thanks.

UPDATE #1 - implementing advice from drew010 from comments section.

I navigated to the download page in the browser and clicked on the link to download the file. Below is the header my browser sent:

```
GET /secure/LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip?signature=4TWzCzq1bGdLXb3l76L6T6ElX1c%3D&issued=1459660640149 HTTP/1.1
Host: resources.lendingclub.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: <deleted for privacy>
```

I then changed the last cURL request:

```
set_time_limit(0); //prevent timeout
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'testfile.zip', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5040);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url3a); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
$headers = array(
    "Host: resources.lendingclub.com",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer: https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'no Curl error';
}
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
var_dump($info);
var_dump($output);
return;
```

Still the same problem. It returns code 401.

Comment: Try adding more HTTP headers (including User-Agent) to try making it look like a real browser.  Also, there's no need to create a new cURL handle every time, you can re-use the same one for each request to make things easier.

Comment: @drew010 thanks for the response. I did inspect the header sent when I download from the browser window and added it to the cURL request. Still doesn't work. I updated the question with the results.

Comment: Can you confirm the cookie file is getting created?   I can try creating an account tomorrow and seeing if I can make it work.

Comment: @drew010 the cookie file is being created. And it works for the first three cURL requests. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @drew010 I finally found the issue. I added an answer to document it for future reference. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It had nothing to do with the cURL request or the 401 code.

I was getting the url for the file I wanted to download by parsing the output of a cURL request (see below):

```
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/resources\.lendingclub\.com\/secure[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $output, $parts);
$url3a = $parts[0][0];
```

The problem is that the url had a "&" that was encoded as "&amp". When I echoed the string to the screen all I could see was the "&", not the "&amp".

So after playing with strlen and strpos I found the issue and solved it by replacing the line:

```
$url3a = $parts[0][0];
```

with

```
$url3a = htmlspecialchars_decode($parts[0][0]);
```

This solved the issue.

Thanks.